# Performance rating returns with no results

Tags: windows-8

I have run the Windows 8 performance tester (orange framed picture) three times, each time returning with the screen seen in the blue framed picture.

It is obvious that the first picture should contain my scores after the first run of the performance test, but does not react at all.

Any ideas? Of course this is not a life or death situation, but I sure would like to get the benchmark.

Ps. My version of Windows 8 is downloaded from DreamSpark for Academic Institutions, former eAcademy: Microsoft Windows 8 Professional 64-bit (English) - it should be the final product

[image]
[image]

Edit: I have tried rebooting the computer.

Comment: I also have my windows 8 from dreamspark via my university and the assessment worked on my two computers. Try restarting the computer? Sometimes it acts weird right after installation when Windows Update is doing its thing in the background.

Comment: I have tried restarting; should have written that ;)

Comment: Can you run `winsat formal` from an elevated Command Prompt and mention error messages, if any, here?

Comment: In some automagical way executing that program triggered the score on the screen. Thanks! Please write it as an answer so I can accept it ;)

Comment: It's possible that the XML file was either corrupt, or permissions were screwy, so the command line fixed that. Very interesting.

Comment: Kind of a freak accident. I'll examine the files later.

Comment: @HenningKlevjer: Posted answer as requested. :)

Comment: Great. Had a look at the files but could not find any visible deviations.. Every attempt was logged successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**WinSAT** (the *Windows System Assessment Tool*) can be run from the command-line as well.

Usage: `WinSAT <assessment_name> [switches]` (for a complete list, see `WinSAT /?`)

`WinSAT formal` will run the full set of assessments, and doing this *may* fix any corruption of the assessment XMLs, or at least display error messages that may help in debugging an issue like this.

Answer (score 3):

The results are pulled from the following file:

`C:\Windows\Performance\WinSAT\DataStore\yyyy-mm-dd hh.mm.ss.ttt Formal.Assessment (Recent).WinSAT.xml`

What does that file look like? On mine, around Column 678, I see `<SystemScore>7.1</SystemScore>`.