# Windows Experience Index could not be computed

Tags: windows-8, windows-experience-index

I've upgraded recently from Windows Vista to Windows 8. When I try to rate my computer, it accesses DirectX 9 performance, then processes to DirectX 10 tests:

[image: Running the Direct3D 10 Texture Load Assessment]

And it gets stuck at this point. In 5–10 minutes, it shows error message:

[image: The Windows Experience Index for your system could not be computed]

The video card is rather old: Mobile Intel 965 Express Chipset Family. I'm pretty sure it does not support DirectX 10. Why does Windows assess it with DirectX 10? And how can I make it skip DirectX 10 tests and get the system rating?

The driver was installed automatically by Windows 8 from Windows Update.
Version: 8.15.10.2697
Date: 10/01/2012

Comment: Any reason why you care about the rating?

Comment: @Karan Windows does not look right without the system rating. Additionally I'd like to know whether the score is different from Vista.

Comment: "Does not look right"? Huh. I've *never* bothered with it TBH and has always looked fine to me! Anyway, will check and let you know if there's any way of skipping the DX10 tests.

Comment: You cannot compare the score between the different OSes.

Comment: @Karan It's because of the first experience. It's there but cannot be computed. WEI was there since Vista, and you look at it after system install. In the long term, knowing the score (or not knowing) does not make any difference, so I agree it's not critical at all. Although if it's possible, it would be great to compute the WEI.

Comment: Open the file "C:\Windows\Performance\WinSAT\winsat.log" and look for the complete error message.

Comment: @Matsemann is that true? In Vista the ceiling was 5.9, then 7.9 in 7, now it's 9.9 in 8. I assumed raising the ceiling in this manner allowed scores to be consistent across OSes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't found a way to skip DirectX 10 testing. On the other hand, I've found a way to fill system rating data so that Windows Experience Index is displayed:

[image: Windows 8: Windows Experience Index displayed]

The following steps explain how to change the displayed numbers. Since I couldn't run the *official* performance testing, I had to cheat.

## WinSAT: Windows System Assessment Tool

Using `WinSAT` command-line utility, I ran all the tests excluding gaming graphics:

```
winsat dwmformal
winsat cpuformal
winsat memformal
winsat diskformal
```

This way I obtained the rating for almost all the components. The results are saved in `%WinDir%\Performance\WinSAT\DataStore\` in XML files.

And then I ran only DirectX 9 subset of `graphicsformal3d` assessment:

```
winsat graphicsformal3d -dx9 -xml d3d.xml
```

I skipped `graphicsformalmedia` assessment as its data are not displayed.

## Formal Assessment Data File

Luckily I had a copy of XML file with *Formal* assessment from another Windows 8 computer. I modified the data in `<WinSPR>` element and put my data into it:

```
<WinSPR>
    <SystemScore>3.1</SystemScore>

    <MemoryScore>4.4</MemoryScore>
    <CpuScore>4.8</CpuScore>

    <CPUSubAggScore>4.1</CPUSubAggScore>
    <VideoEncodeScore>3.9</VideoEncodeScore>

    <GraphicsScore>3.1</GraphicsScore>

    <Dx9SubScore>4.1</Dx9SubScore>
    <Dx10SubScore>5.6</Dx10SubScore>

    <GamingScore>3.3</GamingScore>

    <StdDefPlaybackScore>TRUE</StdDefPlaybackScore>
    <HighDefPlaybackScore>TRUE</HighDefPlaybackScore>

    <DiskScore>5.1</DiskScore>
</WinSPR>
```

In my case, the file is named [`2012-12-03 12.12.03.212 Formal.Assessment (Recent).WinSAT.xml`](https://malyek.net/misc/windows8/2012-12-03%2012.12.03.212%20Formal.Assessment%20%28Recent%29.WinSAT.xml).

After modifying the XML file, the system displayed the data but complained the data were *out of date*. To fix it, I copied the data starting with `<SystemConfig>` up to the end from one of the formal assessments generated above.

### Inconsistencies

I didn't modify the data in `<Metrics>` element, so they're incorrect.
Additionally, the data in `<Dx9SubScore>` and `<Dx10SubScore>` are inconsistent with `<GamingScore>`.

The inconsistencies can be fixed by copying the data from the formal sub-assessments. My goal was achieved: Windows displays the Windows Experience Index, so I left those unchanged.

## Acknowledgements

The answers to [Performance rating returns with no results](https://superuser.com/questions/491679/performance-rating-returns-with-no-results) showed me the way to go. I learned about `WinSAT` and how Windows stores its Performance data that are displayed as Windows Experience Index.

Comment: Excellent answer! In my case, the error occurred when running `winsat memformal`. The error was: "Error: The buffer size is too big.  Max is 32MB" . To solve this error, Microsoft ("WinSAT test fails in Windows 7") recommends a workaround:  `winsat memformal -buffersize 32MB`. This way I got the corresponding score and followed the method outlined by Alexey.

Answer (score 1):

DirectX 9 is listed as minimum requirement for Windows 8, but [the system requirements](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/system-requirements) also list DirectX 10 as required by "some games or programs", which would make sense why Windows Experience Index (WEI) requires you to have DX10 capabilities present.

Generally speaking, I wouldn't recommend using WEI as a general measurement of how well your machine performs. The way I see it is that it merely measures you, which part of the system is the potential performance bottleneck for Windows.

If you want to measure the overal performance of your system I'd much rather recommend using some other metrics, like free memory, CPU benchmarks, etc. Personally I'd start by getting measurements with some version of [3DMark](http://www.3dmark.com/).

Comment: Aero does not require DX10: it requires DX9 and Aero works perfectly well.

Comment: Clarification: Aero Glass requires DX10. But hmm.. wasn't that removed from Windows 8 in the first place. Maybe they just include DX10 benchmarks for "just in case"?

Comment: Please see the revised answer.

Comment: No, it's not: “[Aero requires](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Troubleshoot-problems-with-Windows-Aero) a **DirectX 9 class graphics processor** that supports a Windows Display Driver Model Driver, Pixel Shader 2.0 in hardware, and 32 bits per pixel.” Vista Home Premium perfectly ran with Aero Glass effect.

Comment: Seems like I'm mistaken. Edited.

Comment: Aero is part of Windows 8, it's only the glass effect that was removed. The desktop still uses it: Aero Peek works the same way as in Windows 7. Even more, desktop composition (Aero) cannot be turned off in Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to roll back to the latest Windows 7 drivers, version 8.15.10.2555.

To do this you need to modify the installation INF file to allow installation on Windows 8 and then use advanced reboot to allow Windows 8 to install the unsigned driver. See instructions at [TachisAlopex](http://tachisalopex.blogspot.com.au/2012/04/windows-8-and-intel-graphics-driver.html): Windows 8 and Intel graphics driver to patch the INF file, but I just used General - Advanced startup in the Windows 8 settings to load the unsigned driver.

Seeing as the Windows 7 drivers version 2555 work fine in Windows 8 with Open GL 2.1 support, I can't understand why the official version 2702 Windows 8 drivers removed it.

http://communities.intel.com/message/166171#166171